# remove the second occurrence of array object with same name

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have this array (java script array of objects)

```
users=[{name:'arrow',age:50,id:444}
       {name:'bow',age:66,id:884}
       {name:'arrow',age:30,id:99},
       {name:'apple',age:50,id:999}
       {name:'bow',age:50,id:9669}]
```

I want to remove second occurrence of same name , in this case , I want to remove  `{name:'arrow',age:30,id:99} and {name:'bow',age:50,id:9669}` and retain first occurrences`{name:'arrow',age:50,id:444} and {name:'bow',age:66,id:884}`

**Resulting array should be :**

```
users=     [{name:'arrow',age:50,id:444}
           {name:'bow',age:66,id:884},
           {name:'apple',age:50,id:999}]
```

Comment: easy, remove the ones that have a duplicate name - using filter though, your input array is invalid

Comment: @OP, Please share what steps you have taken & any code that you have developed until now. If there are any error/s and/or issue/s faced with the code you developed, please describe those as well.

Comment: `users.filter(({name:x},i,a)=>a.findIndex(({name:y})=>x===y)===i)`

Comment: Please try this: `console.log([...new Set(users.map(({ name }) => name))].map(n => users.find(({ name }) => name === n)));` and share your feedback. If it's not already clear, we can progress further (may be to add an answer with explanation); else, it's all good. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const users = [
    { name: 'arrow', age: 50, id: 444 },
    { name: 'bow', age: 66, id: 884 },
    { name: 'arrow', age: 30, id: 99 },
    { name: 'apple', age: 50, id: 999 },
    { name: 'bow', age: 50, id: 9669 }
]

const uniqueUsers = users.reduce((acc, user) => {
    if (!acc.find(u => u.name === user.name)) {
        acc.push(user)
    }
    return acc
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the approach of array.filter:

```js
function removeDuplicateKeyFromArray(arrayOfObjects,keyName){
  keyHolder = {}
  arrayOfObjects.filter((obj)=>{
      if(keyHolder[obj.keyName]){
         return false 
       }
      keyHolder[obj.keyName] = 1 //or true
      return true
    })
}
```